# How to call a variable in one component from other in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular-dart

I have an image uploader in a component com-A

com-A

```
 uploadImage(){
    if(sucess) {
      this.profileImage = response().image;
   }
```

I have a navbar in com-B

com-B

```
  this.navbarImage = imageUrl;
```

I want this.navabarImage to be response().image i.e latest image.

I want to update the image in navbar with the latest changed image but I am unable to call the varable in com-B from com-A

Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to check the [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) section from the Angular fundamentals. I'll provide you with an example to your problem:

1. Create a service that would expose a method to notify any other part of the application that the image has been changed:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class NavbarService {
  // Observable string source
  private profileImageUpdatedSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string stream
  profileImageUpdated$ = this.profileImageUpdatedSource.asObservable();

  // Service message command
  updateImage(url: string) {
    this.profileImageUpdatedSource.next(url);
  }
}
```

2. Inject `NavbarService` into your com-A and call `updateImage` method after the 
   image is being updated:

```js
uploadImage() {
    if(sucess) {
      this.profileImage = response().image;
      this.navbarService.updateImage(this.profileImage);
    }
}
```

3. Inject `NavbarService` into your com-B and subscribe to `profileImageUpdated$`:

```js
export class ComponentB implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private navbarImage: string;
    private profileImageUpdated$: Subscription;

    constructor(private readonly navbarService: NavbarService) { }

    ngOnInit() : void {
        this.profileImageUpdated$ = this.navbarService.profileImageUpdated$
            .subscribe(url => this.navbarImage = url);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // do not forget to unsubscribe
        this.profileImageUpdated$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Refer to [this section](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To share data between components, you can use a service. I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

The basic service code looks like this:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable() 
    export class DataService {
      serviceData: string; 
    }
```

Where "serviceData" in my example would be whatever properties you want to share, such as your image. See the link for details on how to use this service.

Comment: Hi DeborahK,great to you see you here.I started learning Angular from your tutorials only.From the plunkr you provider,i see go to A and Go to B but in my case i should not go to anycomponent.I need to see change in B component from A still being there in A  component only.

Comment: :-) The blog post is just a general example. Change the details to match your requirement.